Couldn't resolve component "default"
I'm running Vue Nuxt, and after introducing layouts, I keep getting errors in my Error.vue.
It is not consistent, as far as I can tell, and I have not received it myself. In error. Vue, I sent an email to myself, and that is how I discovered it. I have never heard any complaints from visitors/customers. It is showing up randomly on different pages, both static and dynamic routes.
Does anyone know where to start looking? If any part of the code needs to be shared, I'll be happy to, but I don't know what code to share.

Couldn't resolve component "default"


It could be anything. E.g. https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/493#issuecomment-856375161 . If you're able to get  the error in console, you need to walk through call stack and debug under which conditions the error is possible, this can give a hint on the problem, and set conditional breakpoints if you can make it occur again during debugging session. "I sent an email to myself, and that is how I discovered it" - if you can consistently reproduce the problem this way, you need to clone the project and isolate it to the point you have "hello world" app that can reproduce it.

This might be an issue with a package incompatibility with Vue2/Vue3. You can put a Sentry in place to maybe narrow down the debugging and have the errors directly sent to you.

I cannot reproduce. I have never received the error myself. This is on prod, and the errors are coming from other visitors.
